# Spark SQL - Scala - Aggregate Function as Parameter to Create DF Column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, higher-order-functions

I am trying to create a function in which I pass as main parameters:

- a DataFrame
- another function (an aggregate: count, countDistinct, max, etc.)

My goal is to return a DataFrame with a new column based on the function provided.

I am having trouble with typing, though. I have been searching around here and most of what I found points to UDFs, and the need to create it in order to apply it in "withColumn".

When I run something like this:

```
    val DF1 = Seq(
  ("asd", "1", "search", "otpx"),
  ("asd", "1", "xpto", "otpx"),
  ("asd", "2", "xpto", "otpx"),
  ("asd", "3", "xpto", "otpx"),
  ("asd", "3", "search", "otpx"),
  ("asd", "4", "search", "otpx"),

  ("zxc", "1", "search", "otpx"),
  ("zxc", "1", "search", "otpx"),
  ("zxc", "1", "search", "otpx"),
  ("zxc", "1", "search", "otpx"),
  ("zxc", "2", "xpto", "otpx"),
  ("zxc", "3", "xpto", "otpx"),
  ("zxc", "3", "xpto", "otpx"),
  ("zxc", "3", "xpto", "otpx"),

  ("qwe", "1", "xpto", "otpx"),
  ("qwe", "2", "xpto", "otpx"),
  ("qwe", "3", "xpto", "otpx"),
  ("qwe", "4", "xpto", "otpx"),
  ("qwe", "5", "xpto", "otpx")

).toDF("cid", "cts", "type", "subtype")

DF1.show(100)

val canList = List("cid", "cts")

def test[T](df: DataFrame, fn: Column => T, newColName: String, colToFn: String, partitionByColumns: List[String]): DataFrame = {

  val window = Window.partitionBy(partitionByColumns.head, partitionByColumns.tail:_*)

  val fun: (Column => T) = (arg: Column) => fn(arg) // or right away udfFun = udf(fn)

  val udfFun = udf(fun)

  val ret = df.withColumn(newColName, udfFun(df(colToFn)).over(window))

  ret
}

val DF2 = test(DF1, countDistinct, "count_type", "type", canList)

DF2.orderBy(canList.head, canList.tail:_*).show(100)
```

I get errors like:

> No TypeTag available for T
>
> val udfFun = udf(fun)

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that `countDistinct` is not supported over a Window. If you want to define a function that takes other aggregate functions over a window (say `count`), you can define `fn` as a function that takes a column and returns a column. UDFs are not appropriate here because you are calling Spark SQL functions, not custom Scala functions.

```
def test(df: DataFrame,
         fn: Column => Column,
         newColName: String,
         colToFn: String,
         partitionByColumns: List[String]
): DataFrame = {
  val window = Window.partitionBy(partitionByColumns.head, partitionByColumns.tail:_*)
  val ret = df.withColumn(newColName, fn(col(colToFn)).over(window))
  ret
}

// calling the function
test(DF1, count, "count_type", "type", canList)
```